# Check existing of a pair attributes

Tags: yii2

I have a form model which creates record in the table. The table contains "many-to-many" relations. I want to check existing of the relation due creation of new one. So I did this validator:

```
[
    ['baseId', 'companyId'], 'exist',
    'targetClass' => CompaniesToBases::class,
    'targetAttribute' => ['baseId' => 'base_id', 'companyId' => 'company_id'],
],
```

And it doesn't work. No errors, no messages in the debugger. And it allows to create same records in the table. Any ideas how to make it right?

Comment: In case of the `ExistValidator` the values passes the validation when they already exist in DB. If you are looking for something that would fail validation when value exists then you need to use `UniqueValidator`. See [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator)

Comment: Did this: `['baseId', 'companyId'], 'unique',`. It works. Thank you.